# Why memory display is wrong in cgdb while set content to null?

Tags: null

**Code**:

```
    unsigned char mac[6];
    memset(mac,'\0',sizeof(mac));
```

[image]

**Question**:
Why I get ONLY 5 \0000 while displaying the MAC memory content at once?
But all elements are exactly NULL.

I tried to set it with other characters, such as @ or $ and etc. It would has exactly 6 characters instead of 5.

Is it a bug with cgdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your debugger is half treating it as a string and half treating it as an array.

You can see quite clearly that there are *six* array elements, `mac[0]` through `mac[5]`.

But, since the `mac` line has decided that it wants to output a string, it's treating the *final* `\0` as the null terminator of said string. In the C world, the *first* such `\0` would be considered the end of the string.

As to whether it's a bug, that depends on what the debugger documentation states. If it states that it will output C-style strings then, yes, it appears to be a bug.

If it *doesn't* say that, it can be written off as an implementation decision or, at worst, a foible.